# Testing maven assembly result

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I have a maven multi module project where two modules of mine should be assembled through the maven plugin for deployment on top of a container.

Let's say my hierarchy is the following

- module1
- module2
- testmodule

I have a test case inside the test module which should retrieve the module1 and module2 assembled jars and try to deploy them on top of a container. Is it possible to do it programmatically, i.e. to walk the maven project through its API and retrieve the filenames of the assembled jars from the project?

Comment: How are you willing to do the deployment of the artifacts to the container?

Comment: through the container api

Answer (score 0):

It is possible because mvn simply calls a Maven startup class but a cleaner way would be to write a plugin that executes as part of the install lifecycle that does the test. That way your "test" of the assembly itself is just an element of the build setup.

Comment: Code for calling maven is in Jenkins/Hudson. You can look at the source of those.

Comment: can you give me a little bit more details?